# PHP uploading issues

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm having strange issues when uploading to the server via PHP.

I get the type of the file (working properly, it shows them via echo)

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$typeFile = end(explode(".", $file['name']));
```

Then I make some comparasions to let them upload it or not, here are the fille types allowed

```
if($file['size'] <= 52428800) { //50MB, and my file is about 2,5MB
    if($fileType == "nlpack" || $fileType == "nl2pkg" || $fileType == "nlpark") {
        $id = add_to_db($file['name']); //Adding to database the name, this will return an id, it works
        if($id) {
            mkdir("uploads/".$id); //create a folder where to add the file, working fine!
            if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']), ".uploads/".$id."/".$file['name']) {
                echo "file uploaded correctly";
            }
            else {
                echo "has been an error"; //it enters here, while the other file types enters in the if()
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Has been an error";
        }
    } else {
        //alert an error
    }
}
```

The thing is, that "nlpack" file type doesn't uploads, and it enters the if() because I checked it with echos, while the other two are uploaded without problem.

I also check the file size, but that's running fine.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show more code? The code in your question doesn't look like is affecting your problem.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Give us something to work with

Comment: don't getting any php error displayed. I will edit it and put all the code as I got it! Give me a minute, thanks to both!

Comment: This code can't work for any file. `if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']), ".uploads/".$id."/".$file['name']) {` should give an error. It should be `if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], ".uploads/".$id."/".$file['name'])) {`

Comment: add_to_db inserts the name of the file to the date base, and returns the id that has generated automatically. Works fine, always is creating the folder with the id returned in mkdir

Comment: just in case, I'll upload the file size, lets see if it's that, but I would say it's not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the filesize isn't exceeding the settings in your php.ini or the file will just fail to upload.

```
upload_max_filesize integer
The maximum size of an uploaded file.

When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used.
```

AND if muliple:

```
max_file_uploads integer
The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously. Starting with PHP 5.3.4, upload fields left blank on submission do not count towards this limit.
```

Comment: OK, in my localhost is just 2MB. Thats why then... Thanks!